# How to install Apple iOS on qemu (it is possible now?)

Tags: ios, installation, qemu

I try to use https://github.com/nvsio/qemu-ios I follow README.txt

It compiles fine:

`./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu --enable-sdl --enable-skinning
  4 make`

But when I run it:

`./arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M ipad1g -option-rom iBoot.k48ap.RELEASE.unencrypted -global s5l8930_h2fmi0.file="0,ce0.bin;2,ce2.bin" -global s5l8930_h2fmi1.file="0,ce1.bin;2,ce3.bin" -pflash ipadnor.bin -gdb tcp::6666 -nographic -S -serial file:serial.txt -monitor stdio -smp 2`

Now getting this error :

`qemu-system-arm: -pflash ipadnor: could not open disk image ipadnor: No such file or directory`

I can't find ipadnor.bin anywhere, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The project has not been update in 4 years, I would say it is pretty dead.